# Why I can't upload a file via flow although it works in debug mode

Tags: visual-workflow, upload

I created a flow for uploading files to quotes. When it runs under edit in debug mode it works well, the files are attached.
But when I run it starting from a button I can't upload the file. The user is the same in both cases, a system administrator.
[image]

The debug log:

[image]
[image]

Debug log on Developer Console:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Same user? Different user? Did you check required permissions?

Comment: What is an error in debug logs?

Comment: Can you please share debug logs of this flow when you run on debug mode? So that we can analyse the same.

Comment: When you run this from the button debug log is generated in the developer console. Can you please provide that also? Before clicking on the button open the developer console and then click on the button so you can find the debug log.

Comment: You need to double-click on the log to open the log file. then post the debug log here.

Comment: [Can't upload](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/320070/community-flow-upload-file-to-custom-object-fails-with-error-cant-upload?rq=1)

Comment: I don't know how but after numerous attempt I've succeeded. Thanks for you quick help!